# Getting an UIView object from its frame position

Tags: ios, uiview

i am developing a project which include multiple view. I know the frame position of a UIView and i need  to get the UIViews' object based on its frame position. I know that we can get the frame of a UIView's object but can i apply it the other way around ?. Any response would be helpfull.

Comment: Checking recursively all childs in ViewController's view's frame to given frame solves the problem but very inefficient one

Comment: Thanks @AlokRao. The accepted answer is something similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could iterate through every subview. I'm assuming you know it will be a UIView instance.

Swift 2.0

```
func checkForViewWithFrame(frame:CGRect) -> UIView? {
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if subview.isMemberOfClass(UIView) {
            if subview.frame == frame {
                return subview
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Instead of complicating things i just went with tags, but thanks for the answer it might help some one else.